# How to access the range of time currently selected on a calendar?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to display a custom UI for entering information on Outlook appointments.

I have this for existing appointments.

I would like to create new appointments by having the user click and drag to select a time range and then trigger the macro. (This works for the built in New Appointment command in Outlook.)

How do I programmatically get the time range selected to create a new appointment via VBA code?

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use the `SelectedStartTime` and `SelectedEndTime`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869571.aspx

```
Public Sub GetNewAppt() 
    Dim exp As Explorer: Set exp = Outlook.ActiveExplorer
    Dim mfCalFolder As MAPIFolder
    Set mfCalFolder = exp.CurrentFolder
    Dim vw As View: Set vw = exp.CurrentView
    If vw.ViewType = olCalendarView Then
        With vw
            Dim objAppt As AppointmentItem
            Set objAppt = mfCalFolder.Items.Add
            objAppt.Start = .SelectedStartTime
            objAppt.End = .SelectedEndTime
            objAppt.Display
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I trigger this with a custom button on the ribbon. Didn't test this 2007 or prior.